# iOS Nexmo SDK call a phone number in app voice custom answer url

Tags: ios, swift, vonage

I am following the Nexmo documentation [here](https://developer.nexmo.com/client-sdk/in-app-voice/getting-started/make-phone-call/android) I cant find the iOS docs anymore (mysteriously)
Specifically the docs talk about the Answer URL it says

> You are expected to replace CALLEE_PHONE_NUMBER with the number to be called. But, ultimately, the number that is actually called is the one supplied in the Answer URL webhook. In a real-life use case, you would create a server component to serve as the Answer URL. The app will send to your backend, through the Answer URL the CALLEE_PHONE_NUMBER, the backend would validate it and then supply it in the JSON returned.

> Note: The gist you created is specific to this tutorial. In a real-life scenario, the Answer URL should be provided by a purposely built web solution. Your backend should provide that can serve custom NCCOs and, for this case, receive and validate the phone number dialled from the app.```

So I created my custom backend that takes in a `?to` parameter which returns valid json like so:
`GET https://mycustomurl.herokuapp.com/hello?to=18052425555`

`[{"action":"talk","text":"Please wait while we connect you."},{"action":"connect","timeout":20,"from":"14697938019","endpoint":{"type":"phone","number":"18052425555"}}]`

I put that custom url into my application in the dashboard like this...
`https://mycustomurl.herokuapp.com/` I have also tried many other variations like full path /hello etc.

When I place the call from my app... how do I reference this endpoint? is the parameter automatically `to` (a nexmo support person told me that)? do i pass in the url?

i have tried all these combos:

```
client.call("https://mycustomurl.herokuapp.com/hello?to=18052428083", callHandler: .server)
client.call("hello?to=18052428083", callHandler: .server)
client.call("18052428083", callHandler: .server)
```

I cannot get it to work and cannot find anything in the docs about how to use the custom backend answer url. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We moved some stuff around, apologies that the redirect didn't work. Here is a [step by step tutorial on making a call from the app](https://developer.nexmo.com/client-sdk/tutorials/app-to-phone/introduction/swift).

Your custom url does not need any parameters, but you will need to update the dashboard to use `https://mycustomurl.herokuapp.com/hello`.

In the app, you call `client.call("44000000000", callHandler: .server)` which will make a GET request to your custom url. The request made to the custom url will have a JSON object in its query which would like like this:

```js
{
  to: '44000000000',
  from_user: 'Alice',
  conversation_uuid: 'CON-7a15150b-121d-42b7-91eb-23ccefdcbf5e',
  uuid: 'NONE'
}
```

The `to` value in the JSON object will be the number provided in the app. You can use this to fill out the NCCO that you would return, for example:

```js
[
    {
        "action": "talk",
        "text": "Please wait while we connect you."
    },
    {
        "action": "connect",
        "endpoint": [
            {
                "type": "phone",
                "from": request.body.from_user
                "number": request.body.to
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! very clear response... I implemented as you described, but my iOS app is not responding. Do i need to return the `conversation_uuid` in my custom answer url to? and what parameter name is that expecting?

Comment: 40ad-4f49-ac13-23b8c0d67857&uuid=NONE" host=glacial-bayou-26440.herokuapp.com request_id=77391841-7907-44b1-80bc-56d5226607a3 fwd="169.63.86.174" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=659 protocol=https
2020-08-28T17:40:02.862332+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.167.186 - - [28/Aug/2020:17:40:02 +0000] "GET /hello?to=18052428088&from_user=lhEfbONxfdXWJ64ajq9WfQbn&conversation_uuid=CON-70619c99-40ad-4f49-ac13-23b8c0d67857&uuid=NONE HTTP/1.1" 200 155 "-" "Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1 (Java/1.8.0_66)

Comment: response is ```[{"action":"talk","text":"Please wait while we connect you."},{"action":"connect","endpoint":{"from":"14697938019","type":"phone","number":"18052428088"}}]```

Comment: Figured it out! missing [] around endpooint Thanks for the help!!!